# mysql cross join, but without duplicated pair?

Tags: mysql, cross-join

Let's say I have the following row in my table

**table rows**

```
id
63
64
65
66
67
68
```

if I run the following query, I get 30 rows.

```
SELECT r1.id, r2,id 
  FROM rows AS r1 
    CROSS JOIN rows AS r2 
  WHERE r1.id!=r2.id
```

**result:**

```
63  64
65  64
66  64
67  64
68  64
64  63
65  63
66  63
67  63
68  63
63  65
64  65
66  65
67  65
68  65
63  66
64  66
65  66
67  66
68  66
63  67
64  67
65  67
66  67
68  67
63  68
64  68
65  68
66  68
67  68
```

how would I get the following result instead of the above?

```
63,64  
63,65   
63,66
63,67
63,68

64,65
64,66
64,67
64,68

65,66
65,67
65,68

66,67
66,68

67,68
```

as you see, I don't want to get both 63,64 and 64,63, for example.

Comment: Preceding each line with four extra spaces should be used for lines you want to mark as code. To preserve spacing in text that isn't code, use `<pre>`.

Comment: @outis // thank you for the editing!

Comment: normally I like to [set a man on fire](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/build_a_man_a_fire-and_he-ll_be_warm_for_a_day/225760.html), but you already know what four spaces does in Markdown.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple, only join with values higher than the current one.

```
select r1.id, r2,id 
from rows r1 
cross join rows r2 
where r1.id < r2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add one condition. Left side to be always smaller then right. This will eliminate all the unwanted cases.

```
select r1.id, r2,id from rows as r1 cross join rows as r2 where r1.id!=r2.id and r1.id <r2.id
```