# Fetch data from multiple unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider these 2 tables:

```
Product1
----------
id
created

Product2
---------
id
created
```

How can I get all products from `Product1` and `Product2` ordered by `created`?

NB: `Product1` and `Product2` tables are only examples to explain my case, they do not reflect the reality. Please do not debate about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[You can Combining Result Sets by Using MySQL UNION](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)**

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e2f74/5)

```
SELECT * FROM (select p1.id, p1.created from product1 p1
UNION ALL
select p2.id, p2.created from product2 p2) A 
order by created
```

**OR**

```
(select p1.id, p1.created from product1 p1)
UNION ALL (select p2.id, p2.created from product2 p2)
ORDER BY created
```

Comment: Results should be ordered as OP stated.

Comment: @ElonThan modified answer using Order By clause.

Answer (score 1):

assuming both tables have an identical structure you could try this

```
SELECT
    'Product1' AS FromTable
    ,id
    ,created
FROM
    Product1
UNION
SELECT
    'Product2' AS FromTable
    ,id
    ,created
FROM
    Product2
ORDER BY created
```

Comment: If the tables are mutually exclusive, then use UNION ALL as it is faster.

Comment: Results should be ordered as OP stated.

Comment: yep but i cannot use orderby

Answer (score -3):

Use cross join (also known as Cartesian join)

```
select product1.*, product2.* from product1 cross join product2;
```

just be cautions that what the cross join does it multiplies the records. Here is an answer for that [mysql cross join, but without duplicated pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381757/mysql-cross-join-but-without-duplicated-pair)